# error javascript codigo

Tags: javascript

hice este ejercicio donde el usuario ingresa un numero y el programa no aceptara negativos ni letras. despues dira si el numero es una unidad, decena, o centena
el problema es que no compila ni funciona. me ayudan por favor

'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

```
alert("ESTA VEZ SERA DIFERENTE.");


function osa(){

    var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("escribe un numero: ",0));

    

    while(numero1 <= 0 ||  isNaN(numero1)){

        numero1 = parseInt(prompt("MAL... escribe un numero entero ",0));
       
    }

    if( numero1 >= 1 || numero1 <= 10 ){

        document.write("tu numero es una unidad ");

    } else if( numero1 >= 10 || numero1 <= 100){

        document.write("tu numero es una decena ");

    } else if( numero1 >= 100){

        document.write("tu numero es una centena ");
    }

    }

    osa();

    })
```

Comment: Cual sería el problema? no veo ningún error en tu código...

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas:

1. En javascript no se compila se interpreta.
2. Debes prefir usar `Number` por sobre `parseInt`, este último si acepta letras, por ejemplo

```js
console.log(parseInt("123 acepto letras")); //123
console.log(Number("123 no acepto letras")); //NaN
```

3. Tus condicionales estan mal, por ejemplo:

`if( numero1 >= 1 || numero1 <= 10 )`

Acepta cualquier número mayor-igual a 1 **Ó** menor-igual a 10, es decir te puede aceptar mil millones porque es mayor que 1. Un `or` se evalua de izquierda a derecha, si encuentra un true no sigue evaluando. Por lo tanto, en tu caso cualquier número mayor o igual a 1 nunca evaluará `numero1 <= 10`. En otras palabras deberías haber ocupado un `and`. Lo mismo sucede para los otros `if`

Pero no solo eso, tú pones `numero1 <= 10` es decir que estás tomando el 10 como unidad. También tienes este error en los otros `if`. Entonces tu condición debería ser:

`if( numero1 >= 1 && numero1 <= 9 )`

*Luego está el tema del cero que no lo consideras como unidad, pero este tema ya es de definición matemática que no me interesa ahondar.*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

 function osa(){

    var numero1 = Number(prompt("escribe un numero: ",0));

    while(numero1 <= 0 ||  isNaN(numero1)){
       numero1 = parseInt(prompt("MAL... escribe un numero entero ",0));
    }

    if( numero1 >= 1 && numero1 <= 9 ){
        document.write("tú número es una unidad ");
    } else if( numero1 >= 10 && numero1 <= 99){
        document.write("tú  número es una decena ");
    } else if( numero1 >= 100 && numero1 <= 999){
        document.write("tú número es una centena ");
    } else{
         document.write("tú número es mayor a las centenas ");
    }
 }
 osa();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tu código compila sin errores. Prueba a borrar la caché. Recuerda que siempre puedes abrir la consola del navegador para ver los errores.

He hecho algunas modificaciones al código ya que he visto que no funcionaba como se esperaba.

Simplemente he hecho parseInt en una nueva línea para asegurarme que convertía el valor a int y he arreglado ligeramente los condicionales.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

alert("ESTA VEZ SERA DIFERENTE.");


function osa()
{

    var numero1 = prompt("escribe un numero: ",0);
    numero1 = parseInt(numero1);
    
    if (numero1 >= 0 &&  !isNaN(numero1))
    {
        if(numero1 < 10)
        {

            document.write("tu numero es una unidad ");

        } else if(numero1 < 100)
        {

            document.write("tu numero es una decena ");

        } else if( numero1 >= 100)
        {

            document.write("tu numero es una centena ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("MAL... escribe un numero entero ");
        
        osa();
    }

}

osa();

    })
```

Un saludo, espero que te sirva.